# 500 Internal Error, Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: php, internal

Im having a little issue with my coding, i keep getting a 500 error when i run this script:

```
<?php
include_once("../../includes/connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "check"){
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip-tags($_POST['email']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));

if (strpos($email,"@")!== false){
    $check_email = explode("@",$email);
    if (strpos($check_email[1],".")=== false){
        echo 3;
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo 3;
    exit();
}
$email_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($email_query)== 1){
    //Email already exists
    echo 1;
    exit();
} else {
    $username_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysql_num_rows($username_query)== 1){
        //Username already exists
        echo 2;
        exit();
    } else {
        //Everything is fine
        echo 0;
        exit();
    }
}
}
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "register"){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

    $activation_code = md5($username.$password);

    $reg_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, activfation_code) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$activation_code')");
    if ($reg_query){
        //Successfully registered
        $new_userid = mysql_insert_id();
        //Create new users folder
        #mkdir("../users/$new_userid", 0755);
        //Create new users images folder
        #mkdir("../users/$new_userid/images", 0755);
        //Create new users media folder
        #mkdir("../users/$new_userid/media", 0755);

        $to = $email;
        $from = "noreply@atradiesinc.com";
        $subject = "Activate your Account!";

        $message = "<h3>Welcome to Atradies Inc Gaming Community, ".$username."!</h3>
        <p>To complete registration you must verify and activate your account. Click the link below and the magic shall happen.</p>
        <p><a href='http://www.atradiesinc.com/network/?id=$new_userid&activate=$activation_code'>http://www.atradiesinc.com/network/?id=$new_userid&activate=$activation_code</a></p>
        <p>Once your account has been activated, you may login and join in with the community with the details below:<br />
        <strong>Username: </strong>$username<br />
        <strong>Password: </strong><i>Password you supplied on registration</i></p>
        <p>Thank you and enjoy the community!</p>";

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo 1;
        exit();

    } else {
        //Registration failed
        echo 0;
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Whats the problem? I cant seem to find any issue with it. Is it the code, or is it the server im trying it out on? Ive tried the Chrome Inspect Element console and it doesnt give any more information then '500 Internal Server Error' on that file.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into your webservers `error.log`, or enable PHPs.

Comment: Check your server logs.  The error is on the server side, not the browser side, so Chrome's "inspect element" feature won't help you.

Comment: Try to add this at the very top of your page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: the mysql_* function are deprecated (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php), use mysqli_* - and you have a typo in `strip-tags($_POST['email'])`

Comment: $activation_code = md5($username.$password) is very insecure. Try $activation_code = md5(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));

Comment: Wow, thanks pce, that was the issue. Thanks very much!

Comment: Typo related questions (and those identified simply as such) are off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little typo in the third line:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip-tags($_POST['email']));
```

should be

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
```

And have a look at the comments, they are quite important.